# CentOS 5 domain-search from DHCP server ignored by dhclient

Tags: centos, dhcp, dhclient

I have a DHCP server running ISC dhcpd which offers the `option domain-search "domain.local";` option.

This is being ignored by a particular CentOS 5 dhclient which is removing the search parameter in `resolv.conf` even if I add it in manually and restart networking.

When looking at the dhclient lease in `/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases` I notice that the `option domain-search` is not among the options it's received from the DHCP server.

I'm aware that you can set a `dhclient.conf` file to locally override options received from DHCP servers but there doesn't appear to be an `/etc/dhclient.conf` or `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

It's strange that it's being actively overwritten and not in the local leases file. CentOS 6 guests appear to be receiving the option ok.

Anyone aware of any other conditions where this might happen?
OS is CentOS 5.8 64bit and dhclient 12:3.0.5-33.el5_9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Basically it appears that `dhclient` with CentOS 5 doesn't recognise the `domain-search` option from `dhcpd`, whereas CentOS 6 does.

I additionally specified the `domain-name` option in `dhcpd.conf` and a networking restart on the CentOS guests got the `search` parameter added to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Hope this helps someone out.